# What does a Haskell type error mean when it includes: "... is as general as its inferred signature ..."?

Tags: haskell

**Edit:** [@luqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47232769/what-does-a-haskell-type-error-mean-when-it-includes-is-as-general-as-its#comment81420041_47232769) is onto something, with a much simpler reproducible case in GHCi:

```
Prelude> let (a, b) = ('x', return 'y')

<interactive>:1:5: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `m0'
      prevents the constraint `(Monad m0)' from being solved.
    * When checking that the inferred type
        a :: forall (m :: * -> *). Monad m => Char
      is as general as its inferred signature
        a :: Char
```

But then how come all the following variants work?

```
Prelude> let c = ('x', return 'y')
Prelude> :t c
c :: Monad m => (Char, m Char)
Prelude> let d = 'x'; e = return 'y'
Prelude> :t d
d :: Char
Prelude> :t e
e :: Monad m => m Char
Prelude> :t (d, e)
(d, e) :: Monad m => (Char, m Char)
Prelude>
```

Shouldn't all of these work the same way?

---

Original question:

Here is a specific example:

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘m0’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Monad m0)’ from being solved.

• When checking that the inferred type
    logger :: forall b t (m :: * -> *).
              Monad m =>
              Data.Text.Internal.Text -> IO ()
  is as general as its inferred signature
    logger :: Data.Text.Internal.Text -> IO ()
```

And [here](https://gist.github.com/Wizek/396b0a608fa93d7d458a78dbf7c88870) is some background information and some instructions to reproduce the error in the above specific case.

But I'm curious even in the general case: under what circumstances can this error arise, and what is it trying to convey?

Comment: I think this would probably be a good question if you added code that could reproduce this sort of error

Comment: I don’t want to leave an answer as I’m not very sure but here’s a guess. You have written a type signature and ghc wants to check that the function for which the type was fully inferred is of that type. Ie it wants to check that the type signature give is a special case of the inferred type. In this case the problem is that the function uses an arbitrary monad which could be anything. The inferred type signature captures this whole the signature does not.

Comment: This error can be seen in `ghci` if you do `let (x,y) = ("foo", return "bar")`.  It tells me that it has something to do with predicative polymorphism, i.e. that a data structure like a tuple or a list cannot contain a polymorphic type, and there are no applicable defaulting rules.  But it's hard to say without seeing some example code (and that link you gave ... tldr)

Comment: @luqui I think you are onto something! Thanks for the smaller repro case. I've updated my question based on what you wrote. And as you can see in my update, the tuple has no problem holding a polymorphic value. `c :: Monad m => (Char, m Char)`. So I think we are getting closer to understanding this, but we are not quite there yet.

Comment: @jberryman I've updated the question with the code of a smaller reproducible case. And here ( https://gist.github.com/Wizek/396b0a608fa93d7d458a78dbf7c88870 ) you can find a larger motivating example.

Comment: @Wizek, What I meant is a type like `(Char, forall m. Monad m => m Char)`, which is illegal (it was allowed by `-XImpredicativePolymorphism`, which is deprecated).

Comment: Also, the fact that `let e = return 'y'` works is due to `NoMonomorphismRestriction` being on by default in ghci.  In source files it is off by default, and you can `:set -XMonomorphismRestriction` in ghci to get this behavior.  The error message is different though.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you're using a pattern binding.

```
(a, b) = ('x', return 'y')
```

basically does this

```
ab = ('x', return 'y')
a = fst ab
b = snd ab
```

The type of `ab` is

```
ab :: Monad m => (Char, m Char)
```

so `a` has type

```
a :: Monad m => Char
```

What is `m`? It doesn't appear to the right of the `=>`, so it's ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, this is what I came to understand as I wrote my edit as well. But it still doesn't make full sense to me. `fst ab :: Monad m => Char` seems nonsensical to me. Is there any reason for that not to be `fst ab :: Char`? In general, only to propagate the constraints for the type variables that are actually mentioned in the right hand side? Or is propagating 'phantom'/impossible constraints ever useful?

Comment: @Wizek, well, it seems silly here, but in other cases it may be less so. In particular, you're relying on the fact that the `Monad m` constraint is not used to calculate the value of the first component. You probably can't, but what if you use a class dictionary to calculate something of a type that doesn't reflect the instance type?

Comment: "You probably can't, but what if you use a class dictionary to calculate something of a type that doesn't reflect the instance type?" Do you mean this is probably not possible? Because if I understand what you write, I'd lean towards that it isn't possible. Or can you give an example where `C v => (a, v b)`, and `C` could have any effect on `a`? If it were `v a`, sure, but we already have a plain `a` 'unconstrained'. And if this turns out to be impossible, wouldn't it make sense to fix GHC inferring `Monad m => Char` by making it look at the variables on the right hand side?

Comment: @Wizek, I don't think it's possible for `Monad`, but it's possible for other classes, I imagine. Trying to pin down a sensible rule smells hard.

Comment: "but it's possible for other classes, I imagine." I'd love to see an example for that! \\\ "Trying to pin down a sensible rule smells hard" Do you mean that you'd find it hard to come up with an example? Or that it would be hard to decide whether to allow or disallow this in GHC?